# How to generate a random string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my form i want to generate random strings for the following fields

```
  f.input :lti_api_key, label: "LTI API KEY"
    f.input :lti_api_secret, label: "LTI API SECRET"
```

how can i do that?
Please help me...

Comment: What do you mean *random strings*? Give us an example.

Comment: i just want to generate  a string which is random & unique.

Comment: something like this "2d9492324049139257ac65ff49e97b961d6a657b6f6fa1d144d5af66e364afcb"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your f.input as such

```
<%= f.text_field :name, id: :bug_name, value: "#{SecureRandom.hex(64)}" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can do that:

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.hex(64)
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the string_pattern gem project: https://github.com/MarioRuiz/string_pattern

To install it: `gem install string_pattern`

This is an example of use:

```
require 'string_pattern'
# four characters. optional: capitals and numbers, required: lower
"4:XN/x/".gen    # aaaa, FF9b, j4em, asdf, ADFt
```